# How do I mock a session? When mocking a user, it needs to set session.permanent but is outside of context

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, session

I have a user profile function I want to test.  Inside of it, it carries out flask's login_use functionality, but then references session.  I am trying to mock a session to verify what the function overall is doing.  It seems like this is a bit more tedious than I thought.

```
from flask import session
from flask_login import user_login

# Base function to mock.
def set_user_session(token):
  user=User(token['id'], token['perms'])
  login_user(user, remember=True)
  session.permanent = True
  session["id"] = user.id
  session["perms"] = user.perms
  returns True
  
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
class TestSessionSet(unittest.TestCase):
  def testSuccessfulFn(self):
    with patch("login_user") as loginuser:
      loginuser.return_value = True
      sampleToken = { "id": 5, "perms": []}
      rslt = set_user_session(sampleToken)
      self.assertTrue(rslt)   # It will be more complex because the result from the function is a bit more complex.
```

In the sample above, when running i will get an error on line *sesssion.permanent = True* saying:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
E           
E           This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
E           an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
E           information about how to avoid this problem.
```

I thought there would be a fairly simple way to do this, but I was hoping to mock a session to allow this to work.  It seems though that a session needs a flask app of sorts running as well, which makes me think: Is there fairly simple and straight forward way to mock this out just to validate the function?